# how to exit a std::execution::par_unseq loop based on a condition

Tags: parallel-processing, c++17

I need to exit the loop, if one of my queue elements satisfies a condition. putting break results in a compile error. what is the best way to execute the loop parallel

//code

```
std::deque<element> my_elements;

std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, my_elements.begin(), my_elements.end(),
    [&](auto v) {

    if (v.attribute == something)
    {
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't have what you want here. You'll have to roll your own parallel for_each, or use a regular sequential for loop.

Comment: A quick look at some source code seems to say that **IF** you are using the right version of libc++ built against Intel TBB and you're building with the Intel compiler then an "early exit supported" preprocessor macro will be set and `std::any_of` will do an early exit and cancel other threads.

Comment: Thanks . After exploring a bit i figured out there are parallel versions of std::any_of and std::find_if which fit my requirement

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that won't work. Why? because `break` is a statically scoped operation; i.e, the destination for the `break` is determined at compile time. Putting it into a lambda (w the loop external to the lambda) makes it impossible for the compiler to see where to "break to".

Example w/o parallelism:

```
    vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
        [](int i) { cout << i << ' '; if (i == 5) break; });
    cout << endl;
```

gives me the following error:

```
so.cpp:10:45: error: 'break' statement not in loop or switch statement
     [](int i) { cout << i << ' '; if (i == 5) break; });
```

To answer your question; I don't think there's a good way to break out of `for_each` in a parallel algorithm. For the non-parallel case, you could throw an exception, but that won't work in the parallel case.

Comment: is there any other way to cancel the other threads once the condition is met. Like the Open MP cancel and cancellation points in Open MP 4.0, which sadly is not supported by MSVC compiler.